# Solving Least squares in numpy/scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

## Lucas Kanade Implementation

I am trying to implement the Lucas Kanade algorithm for some project without using any library. I am following [this guide from opencv.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html)

I am stuck in translating least square equation which is below. 
[image: least square]

I am not sure below code is correct method to compute equation?

#### My Code

`inv(X)*np.matrix(T)`

where

X = [image: X]

T = [image: T]

If yes please acknowledge me. If not please provide show how to do it using numpy or scipy.

> I am not sure how to validate the correctness of least square.
>   Otherwise I would not have asked this question

Comment: I am not sure how to validate the correctness of least square.

Comment: What is  the definition of `T` and `X`? Please complete your code!

Comment: @dendragon updated

Comment: No, I mean the code, how are they defined in your code!?!

Comment: If your matrix is invertible, the solution is unique so you don't need least squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have created the two matrices (the first matrix X and the second matrix T) on the right hand side of the equation. Once you have the two matrices, you can do something like this

```
import numpy as np

uvVector = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(X), T)
```

[np.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) does matrix multiplication.

Comment: @percusse add that as an answer please!